# How is Hard Sigmoid defined

Tags: math, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, theano

I am working on Deep Nets using keras. There is an activation "hard sigmoid". Whats its mathematical definition ?

I know what is Sigmoid. Someone asked similar question on Quora: https://www.quora.com/What-is-hard-sigmoid-in-artificial-neural-networks-Why-is-it-faster-than-standard-sigmoid-Are-there-any-disadvantages-over-the-standard-sigmoid

But I could not find the precise mathematical definition anywhere ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

it is

```
  clip((x + 1)/2, 0, 1)
```

in coding parlance:

```
  max(0, min(1, (x + 1)/2))
```

Comment: You should add some references and / or explanation to this.

Answer (score 14):

Since Keras supports both Tensorflow and Theano, the exact implementation might be different for each backend - I'll cover Theano only. For Theano backend Keras uses `T.nnet.hard_sigmoid`, which is in turn [linearly approximated standard sigmoid](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/nnet/sigm.py#L277):

```py
slope = tensor.constant(0.2, dtype=out_dtype)
shift = tensor.constant(0.5, dtype=out_dtype)
x = (x * slope) + shift
x = tensor.clip(x, 0, 1)
```

i.e. it is: `max(0, min(1, x*0.2 + 0.5))`

Comment: Keras' TensorFlow backend has the same math, though implemented by hand. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L1487

Answer (score 3):

For reference, the `hard sigmoid function` may be defined differently in different places. In Courbariaux et al. 2016 [1] it's defined as:

> σ is the “hard sigmoid” function: σ(x) = clip((x + 1)/2, 0, 1) =
>   max(0, min(1, (x + 1)/2))

The intent is to provide a probability value (hence constraining it to be between `0` and `1`) for use in stochastic binarization of neural network parameters (e.g. weight, activation, gradient). You use the probability `p = σ(x)` returned from the hard sigmoid function to set the parameter `x` to `+1` with `p` probability, or `-1` with probability `1-p`.

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02830 - "Binarized Neural Networks: Training Deep Neural Networks with Weights and Activations Constrained to +1 or -1", Matthieu Courbariaux, Itay Hubara, Daniel Soudry, Ran El-Yaniv, Yoshua Bengio, (Submitted on 9 Feb 2016 (v1), last revised 17 Mar 2016 (this version, v3))

Answer (score 1):

The hard sigmoid is normally a piecewise linear approximation of the logistic sigmoid function. Depending on what properties of the original sigmoid you want to keep, you can use a different approximation.

I personally like to keep the function correct at zero, i.e. `σ(0) = 0.5` (shift) and `σ'(0) = 0.25` (slope). This could be coded as follows

```
def hard_sigmoid(x):
    return np.maximum(0, np.minimum(1, (x + 2) / 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2023, the definition used in Tensorflow Keras seems to have changed slightly. The documentation for [tf.keras.activations.hard_sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/hard_sigmoid) states:

> The hard sigmoid activation, defined as:
>
> ```
> if x < -2.5: return 0
> if x > 2.5: return 1
> if -2.5 <= x <= 2.5: return 0.2 * x + 0.5
> ```

Here is some code to plot the function.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
import pandas

x = numpy.linspace(-10, 10, 100) 
a = tf.constant(x, dtype = tf.float32)
h = tf.keras.activations.hard_sigmoid(a).numpy()
s = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(a).numpy()

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'input': x,
    'sigmoid': s,
    'hardsigmoid': h,
}).set_index('input')
ax = df.plot()
ax.figure.savefig('hardsigmoid-keras.png')
```

Below is the output when ran with tensorflow 2.14.0.

[image]